# How to abstract away the usage of browser's window object?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

How would one abstract away the usage of browser's `window` object when using the Aurelia framework? I would like to avoid direct dependency on the browser when using functionality such as `setInterval` or `addEventListener` for example.

Aurelia has something called *Platform Abstraction Library* which in theory should provide the functionality I am looking for. However, I could not find any documentation about it at the time of writing this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Few examples:

```js
import {DOM, PLATFORM, FEATURE} from 'aurelia-pal';

PLATFORM.addEventListener('click', e => ...);
PLATFORM.requestAnimationFrame(() => ...);

let event = DOM.createCustomEvent('foo', { bubbles: true });
DOM.dispatchEvent(event);
let element = DOM.createElement('div');

if (FEATURE.shadowDOM && FEATURE.scopedCSS && FEATURE.htmlTemplateElement) {
  ...
}
```

There's no `setTimeout` / `setInterval` in the PAL- <strike>I think because aurelia doesn't use `setTimeout`.</strike> I've added an [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/pal/issues/5) to get these added.

Comment: Thanks for the examples as well as the GitHub issue!